# how to select from front to back in blender 3D

Tags: blender

I just started using blender an hour ago while watching a tutorial I notice that when the guy on the youtube uses the Select or B key he can select from front to back. What should I do to automatically select from to front to back?[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to achieve this:

1. When in edit mode, press `Z` to turn off solid preview and show wireframe. Then use `B` to select.
2. Press the "Limit selection to visible" icon to make the solid preview transparent. [image]